# c++ diagram entitys links library

Tags: c++, hyperlink, diagram, visio, entities

Does anyone knows any good visual diagram library, that can help me implement faster an application like visio (but simpler of course), that the user can create entities drag them and create links between them (more than one link), and give the possibility to customize the look of each entity.

Does anyone knows anything to do this (c++)

Thanks

Comment: what - the free and open source Dia is not good enough replacement for Visio? http://projects.gnome.org/dia/

Comment: @Nim No, Visio is actually quite usable.

Comment: @unapersson, eh? I meant, why would you write one when there is Dia - which does exactly what the OP requires? Not whether Visio is usable or not...!?!

Comment: @Nim Sorry, I thought you were dissing Visio - Dia isn't generally a good enough replacement for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider using [Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt).